# Discovery devices using React Native Bluetooth Classic on Android 11 or lower

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I am using React Native do develop an app which uses Bluetooth to find a device and connect to it. I found the React Native Bluetooth Classic library from Ken Davidson (https://kenjdavidson.com/react-native-bluetooth-classic/), which works fine with Android 12 or higher, where you must explicitly request user approval for permissions **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT**, and **BLUETOOTH_SCAN**, but for Android 11 it looks like I need approval only for location permissions and **BLUETOOTH_CONNECT**, and **BLUETOOTH_SCAN** everytime return **NEVER_ASK_AGAIN**.

I don't know what am I missing. I added all the permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml** and methods `await RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothAvailable()`  and `await RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothEnabled()` return `true`, but the app freezes at `RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery()` without any errors.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
 <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions for devices on API 29,30. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Request Bluetooth permissions for devices on API 31,32. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
             devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!-- Since Bluetooth is a basic requirement for our app -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="true" />
```

**Access to location and bluetooth method**

```
const requestAccessFineLocationPermission = async () => {

const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(neededPermissions);

setGranted(
  granted['android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'] ===
    PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
    granted['android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'] ===
      PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
    granted['android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN'] ===
    (PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN)  &&
    granted['android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT'] ===
      (PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) 
);
```

};

**Discover devices method**

```
const available = await RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothAvailable();
const enabled = await RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothEnabled();

if (available && enabled) {
    try {
        const unpaired = await RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery();
        const paired = await RNBluetoothClassic.getBondedDevices();
        setAvailableDevices([...paired, ...unpaired]);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
        setLoadingText('');
    }
  } else {
       await RNBluetoothClassic.requestBluetoothEnabled();
  }
```

Comment: If you look at the logs while debugging, do you see the discovery being started on these devices?   I don't remember anything specific (like pair has) based on the version of the device.   I'm fairly certain that this works on Android 11, as the requirement for the original app this was based on had super low versioned requirements.  Can you debug the native code and see if the `DiscoveryReceiver` is getting called and maybe doing something funky?